# Selecting JSON Data from MySQL DB Column and Displaying

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, pdo

I have a MySQL database and one of the columns contains raw JSON data (this is coming from a joomla component that I have no control over).

I need to retrieve this JSON data and manipulate it using PHP. The code I use to retrieve the data is below (i'll tidy this later, demo purposes only);

```
$query = "SELECT text FROM `myTable` WHERE catid = 92";

$result = $conn->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    print("<pre>".print_r($row,true)."</pre>");

    // $array = json_encode($row);
    // echo $array;
}
```

The output of `print_r($row,true)` is [this](https://pastebin.com/t9KJHyW2).

In the commented code above `echo $array` produces https://pastebin.com/YUUMR2ZG

As you can see the array contains a key called `[text]`. This contains all the JSON data.

How can I access this JSON data, specifically the `title` part (`"title":"Waterside Parish"`)

Basically, I need to access the `title` and `text` parts of the array so I can display them in a html table.

Perhaps I'm not encoding / decoding the results properly?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: `Array[0]['text']` and `Array[1]['text']` are json strings. So loop over the array and for each occurance `json_decode()` the text field

Comment: use `json_decode(<your data>, true)`; It will transform data into array. From my opinion, it is much more better than stdClass, which become result of `json_decode(<your data>)`

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode("your data", true); It will transform data into array. From my opinion, it is much more better than stdClass, which become result of json_decode("your data")

generic example:

```
   $object = json_decode('{"a":"b"}', true);
   echo $object['a'];
```

your example:

```
$query = "SELECT text FROM `myTable` WHERE catid = 92";

$result = $conn->query($query);
$data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        
var_dump(json_decode($data[0]['text'],true));
```

Comment: The line `var_dump(json_decode($row['text'],true));` produces `NULL`

Comment: fetchAll get all data, not one line - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php